# Resize Windows 8.1 in VirtualBox Mac

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, macbook-air, windows-8.1

I am using the Windows 8.1 Developer preview and running it through VirtualBox on my MacBook Air 2013 Model. I am wondering if anyone knows how to resize windows 8 to completely fit my screen, at the moment it is quite small on my screen making it hard to use but all of the preset screen sizes in Windows 8.1 don't fit the MacBook Air dimensions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does anything in the user manual state how to resize a window?

Comment: At the moment I have tried terminal commands to VirtualBox and certain apps on Windows 8.1 to try and create a cmd code line to resize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows) to get a fully functioning display driver. After you do this, you'll be able to use Fullscreen and Seamless modes.

To install Guest Additions, click on the Devices menu and select "Install Guest Additions".

[image: guest additions]

<sub>[source](http://ivanprego.com/apple/instalar-windows-8-con-internet-explorer-10-en-tu-mac/)</sub>

Comment: This worked when I then performed a command prompt with QRes.exe